# StackOverflow Error at java.util.AbstractColllection.<init>(Unknown Source)

Tags: java, stack-overflow

I fixed my prior problem yesterday by just separating all the classes into separate files. Nevertheless, I wrote all the code down and seeing no errors was able to compile the program. Or so I thought.

Here's the error code:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
at java.util.AbstractCollection.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.util.AbstractList.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Vector.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Vector.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Vector.<init>(Unknown Source
```

Here are the spots where my I get the errors(marked with problem?)

```
public class GameWorld implements IObservable, IGameWorld 
{
// create collections class
public Vector<GameObject> GameObjectList = new Vector<GameObject>(); // PROBLEM
private Vector<IObserver> ObserverList = new Vector<IObserver>();
    // declare objects
Tank pTank = new Tank(10, 10);
// other objects and variables to declare 
public GameWorld() 
{
 // add objects to GameObjectList
}
// accessors/mutators
}
```

I get another error here

```
public class Tank extends Movable implements ISteerable
     {
 private int armorStrength;
 private int missileCount;
 public Tank()
 {}

 public Tank(int armStr, int misslCt) // problem?
 {
     armorStrength = armStr; // default armorStrength
     missileCount = misslCt; // default missileCount
 }
 public void setDirection(int direction)
 {
    this.setDirection(direction); // get input from left turn or right turn
    // updateValues();
 }
     // access/mutators here
```

I'm stumped on what to do here.

here's the main code

```
public class Starter {

public static void main (String args[])
{
    Game g = new Game();

}
    }
```

which has a Game class that is basically the GUI of the program

```
public class Game extends JFrame { 

 private GameWorld gw; 
 private MapView mv; // new in A2 
 private ScoreView sv; // new in A2
```

public Game() {

```
 gw = new GameWorld(); // create “Observable” 
 mv = new MapView(); // create an “Observer” for the map 
 sv = new ScoreView(gw); // create an “Observer” for the game state data 
 gw.addObserver(mv); // register the map Observer 
 gw.addObserver(sv); // register the score observer 

     // code here to create menus, create Command objects for each command, 
     // add commands to Command menu, create a control panel for the buttons, 
     // add buttons to the control panel, add commands to the buttons, and 
     // add control panel, MapView panel, and ScoreView panel to the frame  



 setVisible(true); 
 } 
     }
```

and has a lot of references to other functions.

Comment: Post your `main` method.

Comment: It seems you are using recursion and it never ends, resulting in stackoverflow. Please post your main method.

Comment: `public class Starter {

 public static void main (String args[])
 {
  Game g = new Game();

 }
}
`

Comment: @thebulge, is that all that's in your `main`? Please post all in your post and not as comment.  Just `edit` your post. Link is below the SO tags

Comment: edited. sorry about that.